# How to disable certain dates in UIDatePicker?

Tags: iphone, datepicker, uidatepicker

I have the object of UIDatePicker and i want to disable certain dates like weekends and holidays is it possible? how?

```
typePicker=[[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[typePicker setMinimumDate: [NSDate date]];
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. The next best thing is probably setting a minimum and maximum date, and upon selecting a date that you don't want the user to select, scrolling to the nearest date that the user can select.

Alternatively, you can create your own UIPickerView that implements this behavior. However, coding this is not something trivial.